# Contextual action bar text forced to use toolbar background

Tags: android, android-toolbar

[image]

Image above shows that the Up Button's back arrow color is white and the background color of the text of the contextual action bar got it from the toolbar. How can I change the color of the text and up button to black? I tried to override `@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode` and change the `actionModeBackground` and `titleTextStyle` but it doesn't fit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

To change up image icon, do this

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back);
```

To change title color:

```
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
```

See if it can help you.